# Implementing Application Insights for Micro Service Architecture

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

We are developing a suite of applications that are architected to use a common layer of Micro-Services with each app having its own UI. Looking for guidance on the best way to implement Application Insights for these apps. Was thinking that we would create an AI instance for each app and then include the app UI along with each of the Micro-Services that support that app. With this approach, the Micro-Services supporting multiple apps would be reporting telemetry to multiple AI instances. Does this approach makes sense to get an end-to-end view of an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Application Insights support correlation across multiple AI instances. So, Application Map, End-to-End UX will work correctly.

Comment: Sorry, that is not really what I asked but it makes me wonder (based one what you said) if it is better to do what I proposed or to put the Micro-Services in their own instance of AI and each app that will use the Micro-Services in its own instance of AI.

Comment: From AI perspective it should not matter much - all apps can report data to the same AI resource, or they can report to individual ones, or any form of mix and match. Correlation will still work. We have lots of customers following each approach.